# Strange command line when opening terminal, after downloading flutter

Tags: macos, flutter, terminal, download

I downloaded flutter yesterday (03/07/21). Today, when I opened Terminal, I got this:

> Last login: Mon Mar  8 08:52:28 on ttys000
> /Users/mateusoliveira/.zshrc:1: /Users/mateusoliveira/Developer/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mateusoliveira/Developer/flutter/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:$PATH:Users/mateusoliveira/Developer/flutter/bin:Users/mateusoliveira/Developer/flutter/bin not found
> mateusoliveira@MacBook-Pro-de-mateus ~ %

What is it referring to?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't put the right path in your PATH environment variable in your `.zshrc` file.